# Win10 going into recovery mode after installing Ubuntu, Gparted shows 290GB partition as unallocated

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, data-recovery, recovery-mode

as done several times before(on other pc's), I installed Ubuntu next to Win10-64bit.
It's a BIOS not UEFI, on an Lenovo Laptop
To summarize:

1. during install using Ubuntu installation resized and partitioned the main HD
2. installed Ubuntu
3. Ubuntu and Windows10 show up in GRUB
4. Booting Ubuntu is OK
5. Booting Windows10 NOT OK, goes into recovering mode, no way to boot into win10, even not safe-mode
6. tried to fix mbr via USB booting, then windows goes directly into recovery mode, no help
7. tried fixing GRUB again, so all entries are there again, same issues
8. Gparted sees the 290GB windows partition, but says it's unallocated, same like empty
9. I did not empty nor format this partition
10. tried several tools like Testdisk and it says that some sectors are not having the correct size

Now I don't really care if Windows is going to run or not, but I need to get the data from that partition like photos and that kind of stuff, else my wife is gonna kill me, so you understand it's a state of emergency...she already got a new laptop.
I'm not being able to select that partition to be able to recover any data or use an undelete program to find data.
Any clue on what I could do on this matter?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is the reason why your #1 is not recommended. You should shrink Windows partitions from Windows with Windows tools an reboot to assure Windows is fine with the new size. This is particularly important if BIOS/Legacy and MBR. Likewise disabling Windows Fast Startup is a must.

Comment: Now you need Windows installation media to repair.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Too bad that it is offered, if not recommended then I think Ubuntu/Canonical should not offer it, because not everyone knows that up front and uses the the tool as is. I've used the Windows Installation media to repair, it gives the same result. It does not repair it correctly, leaving it in an unbootable state. Luckely I have some progress with Testdisk and could recover some media, but not all.

Comment: You're right up to point but then it can (and should) be argued that users installing OSes should (1) have backups and (2) know the requirements and caveats of certain options in both OSes and know that same are often the default but should be disabled anyway for a dual-boot (it takes less than 5 minutes to learn about them).

Comment: Thanks @ ChanganAuto